# Breadth first search in directed graph

Tags: c++, search, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

When performing a breadth first search on a directed graph, and we begin at vertex 1 in the picture below, will vertex 0 ever be visited?

```
              >v4------>v5 
            /
v0------->v1
            \
             > v2-------v3
```

Also, can you guys please confirm with me if I have the concept of BFS? So if we started at v1, we first consider all unexplored paths (in this case the paths from v1 to v4, and v1 to v2, but NOT v1 to v0 because it isn't possible), then we visit the vertices v4 and v2, and order does not matter. Then, depending on which ever vertex was last visited, we check for unexplored paths (if we're at v4, the unexplored path would be from v4 to v5, so we travel along that and then visit v5). After that, we check v2 for unexplored paths, in this case v2 to v3, and visit v3. Now v3 does not have any other unexplored paths so we check v5, which also does not have any unexplored paths. Now do we end our BFS? Or can we somehow visit v0?

Also, if instead we had used a DFS and started at v1, would we then eventually visit v0? If DFS was used, would the order of vertices visited, assuming v2 is left of v1, be v1,v2,v3,v4,v5, and then v0?

Comment: You can use either BFS/DFS to visit all nodes in a graph. But to visit all nodes
you might have to call BFS/DFS procedure more than once.

Comment: @sasha Thanks for reply, if I called BFS once, and started at v1, would it be true to say that v0 would never be visited? Also, if I called DFS just once, would all the vertices be visited in the first pass?

Comment: yes if you just called BFS/DFS only once ie from v1 you will not visit v0

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of the BFS appears to be correct. DFS is also correct (up to vertex v5).

In neither case would you arrive at v0 if you start at v1 as there is no directed edge leading into v0 in your diagram.

Comment: Thanks jc for the comment. So if there is a directed edge, in either case of DFS or BFS, it would be impossible to ever reach v0 if we started at v1?

Comment: In the diagram you have drawn in your example, that is correct. There is nothing stopping you from having a new graph with a directed edge leading - for example - from v3 to v0, which would allow you to reach v0. Of course, in this case your BFS/DFS search algorithm would need to detect cycle in your graph to prevent an inifinite loop.